# How can I have the same keyboard shortcuts across Mac/Windows

Tags: windows, macos, phpstorm

I love the shortcuts that mac has in PhpStorm - i.e. <kbd>Cmd + R</kbd> is so easy to hit if you're running things all the time.

I want to mimic the same behavior in Windows so I'm not confused when switching between the two. But when I choose the Mac OSX keymap in Windows it assumes I have a `Meta` key, so a lot of the shortcuts don't work.

Anyone out there put out a keymap that solves this (i.e. maps the meta key to `Ctrl`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **MAC** and want to configure some **Windows** hotkeys:

- Use https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

If you are in **Windows** and want to configure some **MAC** hotkeys:

- Install https://www.autohotkey.com/
- Add to it one of these two configurations:
  a) https://gist.github.com/fljot/58e46c92e99e7072ab56
  b) https://github.com/stroebjo/autohotkey-windows-mac-keyboard